# Java Execution Run Time of Bubble vs Selection Sort

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am a novice programmer and am currently on break so I am just trying to polish up on my skills before I start school again. I have written some code that will create an array of 100 elements and populate all 100 indexes with a random number between 0 and 250.

I have written code to sort this array using bubble sorting algorithm and also selection sorting algorithm (I plan to do all known array sorting algorithms and compare execution times.) I have notice that my run time for selection sorting is MUCH faster than bubble sort.

Example run: Bubble sort time: 7.45 ms ------ Selection sort time: 0.15 ms

So my question is.. Have I messed something up or are these results normal?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Bubble {

        private static int[] myArray;
        private static int[] myBubbleArray;
        private static int[] mySelectionArray;


public static void main(String args[]){

    createList();
    fillArray();
    print("Original Array: ", myArray);
    long selectionStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    selectionSortArray(mySelectionArray);
    double selectionElapsedTime = (System.nanoTime() - selectionStartTime) / 1000000.0;     
    print("Selection Sorted Array: ", mySelectionArray);
    System.out.printf("Total execution time for selection sort is %.2f ms\n", selectionElapsedTime);
    long bubbleStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    bubbleSortArray(myBubbleArray);
    double bubbleElapsedTime = (System.nanoTime() - bubbleStartTime) / 1000000.0;
    print("Bubble Sorted Array: ", myBubbleArray);
    System.out.printf("Total execution time for bubble sort is %.2f ms\n", bubbleElapsedTime);
}

private static int[] selectionSortArray(int[] array) {
    int first;
    int temp;
    for(int i=array.length -1; i > 0; i--){
        first = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            if(array[j] > array[first]) first = j;
        }
        temp = array[first];
        array[first] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
    return mySelectionArray;
}

private static int[] bubbleSortArray(int[] array) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int temp;
    while(swapped){
        swapped = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i ++){
            for(int j = 1; j < array.length - i; j++){
                if(array[i] > array[i+1]){
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i+1];
                    array[i+1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return myBubbleArray;
}

public static int[] createList(){
    myArray = new int[100];
    return myArray;
}

public static void print(String n, int[] array){
    System.out.print(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
        System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void fillArray(){
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i ++){
        Random rand = new Random();
        myArray[i] = rand.nextInt(250);
    }
    myBubbleArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length);
    mySelectionArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length);
}
}
```

Comment: It is possible that the JIT compiler heavily optimises your benchmarking code (eliminating dead code etc.) and this is causing the significant difference in execution time. For this reason, writing reliable micro benchmarks is very hard without a proper harness, such as [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). [Avoiding Benchmarking Pitfalls on the JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html) gives a good overview on the topic.

Comment: I tried running your code with the `-Xint` VM option, which should disable all JIT compiler optimizations. The 100x time difference is still clearly visible (selection sort taking a consistent 0.1ms and bubble sort taking ca. 10ms). So it seems that your benchmark is legit.

Comment: Okay this is good to hear. Thanks for the responses Mick!

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the JIT compiler would have acted on this code anyway. Oracle's Hotspot compiler only bothers compiling code that has been run many thousands of times, which this piece of code isn't doing. However, you should be aware that System.nanotime doesn't guarantee nanosecond precision. On most platforms, the precision is much worse, and may even be no better than something in the order of milliseconds. To get an accurate timing, it's better to time a loop that calls the sorting method N times, and divide by N.

Answer (score 2):

For an in-depth answer, [go here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13106/why-is-selection-sort-faster-than-bubble-sort). The summary is specifically, Bubble sort requires, on average, n/4 swaps per entry (each entry is moved element-wise from its initial position to its final position, and each swap involves two entries), while Selection sort requires only 1 (once the minimum/maximum has been found, it is swapped once to the end of the array).

In terms of the number of comparisons, Bubble sort requires k×n comparisons, where k is the maximum distance between an entry's initial position and its final position, which is usually larger than n/2 for uniformly distributed initial values. Selection sort, however, always requires (n−1)×(n−2)/2 comparisons.